# GA4 - missing path / url data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I´m unable to display page urls in GA4, could you please help? It does show the page titles correctly.

[image: page titles is shown]

[image: page urls not working]

Thank you.

Comment: How are you sending the pageview? Do you use GTM or gtag js ?

Comment: I´m using this <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-6XD45ZFX9K"></script>
and then this code   
   
        <script>    
        var asmconfig = {
                gaid : 'G-6XD45ZFX9K',
                ad_not_acepted : '',
                ad_acepted : '',
                ad_acepted_stats : '',
                aviso2 : '',
....
        }
        </script> it´s for cookies...you can check it out here https://forbino.com/ .

Comment: it is working now. I did not make any changes. I dont get it.